# error when editing a view:ajax submit is not a function in drupal

Tags: ajax, drupal

I create a view, and then click the + button to get the available selections. I check a box, and hit Add. Then, I get AJAX output to my screen:

```
{ "display": "\x3cform action=\"/Spectrum%20Magnetics/Spectrum%20Magnetics/admin/build/views/ajax/add-item/test/default/field\"
```

My error console in Firefox says:

```
$(this).ajaxSubmit is not a function
```

Source File: http://test.com/sites/all/modules/views/js/ajax.js?s
Line: 74

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't included jquery form plugin . **ajaxSubmit** is not a core jquery function,

See this : http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Comment: i included jquery_form_update and jsalt module but no effects

Comment: @asitha Please check this http://drupal.org/node/796530 , may be it will help you..